# How "bad" is this constructor really?

Tags: javascript, jshint

While following a HTML5 rocks web audio tutorial JSHint gives this warning...

```
W056 - Bad constructor.at line 26 col 73
```

For the following line...

```
var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
```

The JSHint docs explain the warning is issued whenever new is used with an object literal and go on to say that new "is only useful for creating instances of a constructor function and has no sensible meaning when applied to non-function objects or literals."

This strikes me as a reasonable use though, it's succinct and it's pretty obvious what it's doing. I'm therefore minded to throw in an ignore directive /*jshint -W056 */ but I thought I'd ask in case I'm missing something.

So, am I missing something?

Comment: No, you don't miss anything. And I recommend to use ESLint instead of JSHint.

Comment: @Ginden - thanks for the quick reply. I actually do use ESlint and grunt on serious projects but I have JSHint setup in atom with a more relaxed default config for general purpose dickering about where style is not an issue.

Comment: What you're using is just a shortcut for *if..else*, there is no issue with using *new* with a non–function object. BTW, not all functions are constructors. ;-)

Comment: You can avoid this warning by simply splitting the statement `var AudioContextCtor = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var audioContext = new AudioContextCtor();` Or use ESLint ftw :)

Comment: You could also put this above the line: `/*jshint -W056 */`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message you're getting doesn't match the code. New is used with a constructor function. JSHint probably can't tell this though because of the complex expression it's coming from. So it's wrong about there being no sensible meaning.